# Is it possible to set the xaxis to show only start date and end date with matplotlib?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, matplotlib, plot

I am plotting using python3 and matplotlib from a pandas dataframe. My dataframe looks like this:

```
    date      | value1 | value2 | price
 --------------------------------------
   2019-09-01 |  300   |   125  | 850
   2019-09-02 |  400   |   250  | 625
       .      |   .    |    .   |  .
       .      |   .    |    .   |  .
       .      |   .    |    .   |  .
   2019-11-14 |  216   |   543  | 793
```

date is a datetime object, value1, value2, and price are all just ints/floats.
I'm plotting value1,value2 as a stacked bar chart and price as a line in two axes on the same figure using the second axis to display xticks as so (**note**, stacked_bar is a groupby dataframe made from df and price is corresponding price on the dates in stacked bar. My code ex is brief in actually showing this in my plot functions because those aren't the issue, so just trying to give an idea of what I'm using):

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2)
fig.set_size_inches(10,6)
stacked_bar.plot(kind='bar',stacked=True,ax=ax[0])
df['Price'].plot(ax=ax[1])
```

[image]

**Is there an easy way to get matplotlib to display the ending date on here as an xtick ?** I've been trying a million things to get the ticks formatted properly and I can't seem to get the right one. I'm at the point where I'm about to just make the x-axis non visible and display the date range as a label like '9-01 to 11-14'. For reference, in the displayed figure, I'm not making any adjustments to xticks, this is how it displays itself on run.

Comment: This is a matplotlib question, but if you provide a minimal working example (include loadable subset of data), you'll get more responses. The basic idea is to set both xticks and xticklabel on your bottom axis. What I am not clear without your actual data is if  'date' is a string or datetime.

Comment: Can you provide the code for what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

In the following example, the date is set as the index which is used to generate the first and last tick labels:

```py
import numpy as np               # v 1.19.2
import pandas as pd              # v 1.2.3
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  # v 3.3.4

# Create sample dataset
rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=1)
date = pd.date_range('2019-09-01', '2019-11-14', freq='D')
value1 = rng.integers(0, 2000, size=date.size)
value2 = rng.integers(0, 2000, size=date.size)
price = 800 + np.cumsum(rng.integers(-100, 101, size=date.size))
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(value1=value1, value2=value2, Price=price), index=date)

# Create plots with shared x-axis and use_index=False to align them properly
fig, (top, bot) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, sharex=True, figsize=(10,6))
df[['value1', 'value2']].plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, ax=top)
df['Price'].plot(use_index=False, ax=bot)

# Format x-axis ticks
top.xaxis.set_visible(False)
bot.set_xticks([0, len(df)-1])
bot.set_xticks([], minor=True)
bot.set_xticklabels([date.strftime('%m-%d') for date in df.index[[0,-1]]]);
```

[image: first_and_last_ticks]